# Piping core dumps to a zip program on embedded linux (busybox version) fails

Tags: linux, busybox

I am working on embedded Linux with busybox version. For generating linux core dumps, I use

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then I see that I am getting a huge core file (~1GB). Because my application is huge and allocates that much amount of memory.

Now, I am looking for solutions to optimize this large core file.
I found out that (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) I can pipe core dumps to a program. I am trying to  zip the core dump while it is getting generated.

i.e

```
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

| /tmp/shellscript.sh  /tmp/core.%p.gz

cat  /tmp/shellscript.sh
#!/bin/sh
/bin/gzip > "$1"
```

Now, I realize that 'piping core dump to a program' works only on **normal desktop ubuntu system.**

But our target is embedded linux system which use busybox version.  I am wondering when I do exactly the same steps 'piping core dump to a program (in this case zipping) ' on busybox 
then it doesn't produce a core dump at all.

But if I remove the piping option on busybox, then I see a core dump.
i.e

```
root@(none):~ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/tmp/core_top
```

Do you guys here have any inputs why piping core dump to a program doesn't work on embedded linux with busybox version ?

Thanks,

Comment: Even without space between (`|` and `/`) it doesn't produce zipped core file on busybox. I also checked that `/tmp` partition is executable. I tried to zip any other file in `/tmp` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
man 5 core

   *  The program must be specified using an absolute pathname (or a
      pathname relative to the root directory, /), and must immediately
      follow the '|' character.
```

So, there should be no space between `|` and `/`.

Also, is your `/tmp` partition, where the script resides, perhaps mounted with `-o noexec`?

Comment: Even without space between (| and /) it doesn't produce zipped core file on busybox.

I also checked that /tmp partition is executable. I tried to zip any other file in /tmp and it works.